# Xamarin.Forms Help loading Images from Url/Uri directly from viewmodel

Tags: forms, image, xamarin, uri, viewmodel

Im currently working on a cross-platform App (iOS & Android) on Xamarin.Forms My current goal is to develop a slider with images for multiple services.

Something like:

IMAGE  |  IMAGE  | IMAGE | IMAGE

label  |  label  | label | label

scrollable to the sides.

For this I created:

-The Services class

```
string ID
string Name
string ServiceType
ImageSource ImgUrl
```

-A ViewModel (HLandingVM)
Here I prepare the lists objects and load them into the page

-HLandingPage.xaml for the view

-HLandingPage.cs to load the viewmodel

The main issue is that I do see my labels correctly displayed and scrolling as they are supposed to. But the images are not displaying at all.

Ive tryed passing to the model:
An ImageSource , Image by itself, passing just an Uri for the Binding. But the Image will not display at all.

-Class

```
 `private string id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChange("Id");
        }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChange("Name");
        }
    }

    private string servicetype;
    public string ServiceType
    {
        get { return servicetype; }
        set
        {
            servicetype = value;
            OnPropertyChange("ServiceType");
        }
    }



    private ImageSource imgUrl;
    public ImageSource ImgUrl 
    {
        get { return imgUrl; }
        set
        {
            imgUrl = value;
            OnPropertyChange("ImgUrl");
        }
    }`
```

-VIEW

`

```
<StackLayout Margin="10,0,5,0" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150">
   <Image HorizontalOptions="Start"  WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150" >
              <Image.Source>
                  <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding ImgUrl}" />
              </Image.Source>
   </Image>
    <Label Style="{StaticResource BoldLabel}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black"/>
</StackLayout>
```

`

-VM

Adding Services and ImageSources
`

```
Services.Add(
new Services
{
Name = "Service1",
ServiceType = "Owner",
ImgUrl = new UriImageSource()
{
Uri= new Uri("https://via.placeholder.com/150 "),
CachingEnabled = false
}
});
Services.Add(
new Services
{
Name = "Service2",
ServiceType = "Owner",
ImgUrl = new UriImageSource()
{
Uri = new Uri("https://via.placeholder.com/100 "),
CachingEnabled = false
}
});
Services.Add(
new Services
{
Name = "Service3",
ServiceType = "Owner",
ImgUrl = new UriImageSource()
{
Uri = new Uri("https://via.placeholder.com/250 "),
CachingEnabled = false
}
});
```

`

-Trying (not working) to load a Resource Image if the URI returns empty

`

```
foreach (var service in List)
                {
                    if (service.ImgUrl.IsEmpty)
                    {
                        var assembly = typeof(HLandingPage);
                        service.ImgUrl = ImageSource.FromResource("App.Images.150.png", assembly);
                    }
                    OwnerServices.Add(service);
```

`

No aparent erros triggered. Just empty pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help!

**Indeed a string for the image did the trick for the souce binding.**

Another detail I was missing that I noticed 
was setting the ItemsSource in the xaml.cs

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            viewModel.UpdateServices();
            OwnerServicesSlider.ItemsSource = viewModel.OwnerServices;
        }
```

After this Image started showing on the first Item

```
   private string imgUrl;
        public string ImgUrl
        {
            get { return imgUrl; }
            set
            {
                imgUrl = value;
                OnPropertyChange("ImgUrl");
            }
        }
```

I also added the ItemSource to the xaml

```
<controls:HorizontalScrollView HeightRequest="200" 
                                   SelectedCommand="{Binding OpenPageCommand}"
                                   Orientation="Horizontal"  
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding OwnerServices}"
                                   x:Name="OwnerServicesSlider">
                <controls:HorizontalScrollView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Margin="10,0,5,0" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150">
                                <Image HorizontalOptions="Start"  Source="{Binding ImgUrl}" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150"/>
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource BoldLabel}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:HorizontalScrollView.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:HorizontalScrollView>
```

And Im filling my list with different links

```
 Services.Add(
               new Services
               {
                   Name = "Service1",
                   ServiceType = "Owner",
                   ImgUrl = "http://lorempixel.com/150/150"

               });
            Services.Add(
                new Services
                {
                    Name = "Service2",
                    ServiceType = "Owner",
                    ImgUrl = "https://via.placeholder.com/150"

                }); ;
            Services.Add(
               new Services
               {
                   Name = "Service3",
                   ServiceType = "Owner",
                   ImgUrl = "https://www.stevensegallery.com/150/150"


               });
```

The Image from https://via.placeholder.com/150 always show but the other two are not showing with the Binding.
Is there somethign Im missing?

I tryed moving the image in the list to be second or even third but only the placeholder shows in any of the positions.

Answer (score 2):

first, you can simplify your `Image`

```
<Image HorizontalOptions="Start"  WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150" Source="{Binding ImgUrl}" />
```

second, make your `ImgUrl` property a `string`

```
Services.Add(
  new Services
  {
    Name = "Service1",
    ServiceType = "Owner",
    ImgUrl = "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
  });
```

finally, be sure you're not actually including a trailing space in your url

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we usually define the  `imgUrl` as a string type ,just as follows

```
private string imgUrl;
public string ImgUrl 
{
    get { return imgUrl; }
    set
    {
        imgUrl = value;
        OnPropertyChange("ImgUrl");
    }
}
```

And binding like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImgUrl}" />
```

Of course, when you init the value of `ImgUrl`. it should be also be `string` type.

And there is a sample to display image from internet, you can refer to it.
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/GetStarted/Tutorials/ListViewTutorial